# Languages supporting unicode logic operators

Tags: language-features, operators, unicode

Are there any programming languages that support the use of unicode logic operators? For example, many programming languages use "**!=**" as the *"does not equal"* 
operator, but in mathematics the symbol is "**≠**".
Since unicode is now more standardized, why don't programming languages support their use as logical operators? Many of the symbols are on my keyboard, I just hit the `alt` button.

Comment: can you tell me how to type `≠` using my QWERTY keyboard?

Comment: Ever seen an [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) keyboard? No? There is a reason non standard keyboards for programming don't take well.

Comment: @BryanChen `"alt"`+`"="`

Comment: not working on my computer... `alt`+some number does print it, but too hard for me to remember what number

Comment: @BryanChen I use a mac, I also etched the symbols onto the keys.

Comment: My guess is that it's the simple combination of "hard to type" and "even if your language would support it, you'd still need to know the other variants because of the languages that don't".

Comment: @kylek `<alt>=` gives me `½`, if it does anything at all (no output in Firefox)

Comment: @BryanChen On my computer I hold down my menu key then type `=` and `/` and get `≠`. Very easy. The menu key is called the compose key in X-Windows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Yes](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/overview.html?q=unicode#%28part._im~3aunicode%29) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656937/valid-identifier-characters-in-scala) [languages](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html) [do](http://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Unicode.Utf8_core.html#). Why not more? Probably because it's a pain to type. I use all the languages I linked above and I rarely use unicode syntax, it's not on my keyboard and it adds about 0 value to my code.

I'm also aware of the fact that unicode is standardized, but not always implemented well. Emacs had problems with it until quite recently, many languages still are bad at unicode which makes it a pain to parse/autogenerate.

That being said, when I do any literate programming or typeset code in anyway, I do use unicode, but there it's with a simple script to do textual substitutions.

Comment: I wonder why Windows doesn't provide any decent way to type non-ASCII characters on its US keyboard layout?  The Macintosh could easily type the arithmetic operators back in the 1980's, as could by DOS-based text editor.

Answer (score 7):

Julia uses unicode extensively. It allows you to define both operators and variables using unicode symbols.

The best way I found to input the chars is to use the "latex-completions" plugin for Atom, which allows you to replace, for example "\alpha" with "α" just by pressing tab.

I guess since Julia is more oriented towards scientific computing having greek variable names is a big plus for readability (compare gradient_delta with ∇δ). Also, ≠ is slightly better than != or not (=) when you get used to it.

Anyway, at first freely using unicode chars in code seemed quite odd, and I was afraid things would break. Living in a spanish-speaking country I learned to hate programmers who would input accented vowels (á,é,í,ó,ú) in code comments, because it usually wreaks havoc with tools that only support strict ascii. But I must say that in Julia (also in Latex with xetex or unicode support packages) it works perfectly.